# Find with proof all positive integers $n$ such that $2^n + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found this problem in a book and while I understand the given solution, I don't quite understand how somebody would arrive at this solution unless they did out the casework and happened to make the right guesses to solve the problem. Any guidance on solving this from scratch would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One approach would be group theory. $2^n\equiv -1$, so $2^{2n}\equiv 1$, which means $2$ is invertible mod $n$, so $2\in \mathbb{Z}_n^{\ast}$, or there are integers $a,b$ so that $2a+nb=1$.

Comment: What kind of solution was given?

Comment: It was a proof by induction with $3^m|2^{3^m} + 1$ for positive integer $m$ for solutions in the form of $3^m$ and then shows that if $n|2^n + 1$ then $2^n + 1|2^{2^n + 1} + 1$ for solutions in the form of $2^{3^m} - 1$.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind that very complicated formula for the induction proof?

Comment: @Moya Great proof, I thought of it,but you beat me to it,so only fair you get credit for it.

Comment: I had a go at this problem some time ago. One can show that if $n=a,b$ works, then $n=gcd(a,b),lcm(a,b),ab$ all works too. There are infinitely many choices of primes that $n$ can have, but the reciprocal sum of all possible $n$s are finite.

Comment: I was considering using Euler's theorem,but that's basically what Moya did implicitly.

Comment: I suppose that casework was supposed to find the first few cases ($1$, $3$, $9$) then an assumption was to be made that the values $3^m$ for positive integer $m$ would satisfy the problem. The proof was something like this: Let $2^{3^m} + 1 = 3^m * k$ for a positive integer $k$, it follows that $2^{3^m + 1} + 1 = (3^m * k)^3 = 3^{m + 1} * (3^{2m - 1} * k^3 - 3^m * k^2 + k) - 1 = 3^{m + 1} * t - 1$, where $t = (3^{2m - 1} * k^3 - 3^m * k^2 + k)$.

Comment: Ick,ugly proof and definitely doesn't begin the way a conventional induction proof begins. If you asked someone to prove this by induction,they might get baffled because it wouldn't be clear those first 3 cases were needed first.

Comment: @J.July There are other values other than $3^m$ that $n$ can be. For example, check $n=171,13203$. Those are the few others I remember.

Comment: @karvens Yes, after proving the case for $3^m$ it goes on to prove the case for $2^{n} + 1$ and some others I believe but I never got so far as to understand how the $3^m$ case was originally thought of.

Comment: @J.July That's easy,stacks of scratch work that people left out of the proof once they had it. But then it's not really a proof by induction in my opinion because a real proof by induction begins with the expression and case n=1 and goes from there. This is kind of cheating and I doubt anyone else given this expression and told to prove it by induction could do it like this.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Yes, I agree, the induction part seems a bit silly and misleading in terms of the thought process as there are more elegant solutions (as presented here).

Comment: @J.July I attempted a straight induction proof below,but I'm not 100 percent confident about it. Moya's algebra proof above is the best one here so far.

Comment: It's wrong. I deleted it until I can get the bugs out of it.

Comment: Here one may find more material on these numbers $n$:   http://oeis.org/A006521

Answer (score 2):

Solution on : [Proof.pdf](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~chris/papers/n_divides_2to_nplus1.pdf)

Nice paper by TOBY BAILEY & CHRIS SMYTH

Comment: Very nice paper for the beginning computational number theorists!

Answer (score 1):

> **Too long for a comment** : Here are all numbers up to $\dfrac{10^7}2$ which are **NOT** of the form $n=3^k,~$ so that $~\dfrac{2^n+1}n\in$ **N** :

---

$\qquad\qquad\quad n\le10^5\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad n\le10^6\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad n\le\dfrac{10^7}2$

---

$\qquad\qquad$ [image] $\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ [image] $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [image]